# Neo4j Driver in play

Tags: java, neo4j, playframework, connection-pooling, autocloseable

I use a Neo4j java [driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/org/neo4j/driver/v1/Driver.html) in my play app.

Currently I initialize a new driver for every controller (ie. for every http call). When the autoclosable close method runs it seems to block the entire call for about almost two seconds. Running without closing the drivers (obviously a bad idea) cuts my tests down from 25 seconds to 5.

I do suspect I use the driver in the wrong way and I guess I should be using one driver application wide but cannot figure out how. What is the correct way to use the java Neo4j driver in the play framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Javadoc for the [Driver](https://neo4j.com/docs/api/java-driver/current/) interface states:

> Driver implementations are typically thread-safe, act as a template
>   for Session creation and host a connection pool. All configuration and
>   authentication settings are held immutably by the Driver. Should
>   different settings be required, a new Driver instance should be
>   created.
>
> A driver maintains a connection pool for each remote Neo4j server.
>   Therefore the most efficient way to make use of a Driver is to use the
>   same instance across the application.

So, generally, you should use a single `Driver` instance.

One way to share the same instance is to implement a factory class that provides a [singleton](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples) `Driver` instance. Here is a very basic thread-safe example:

```
class DriverFactory {
    private static Driver instance;
    public static synchronized Driver getDriver() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = GraphDatabase.driver(...);
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: **Exactly** what I was looking for.